# Как в Net 6 из middleware перенаправить вызов на endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net-6

Проект был написан на Net Core 2.2 и такая конструкция работала:

```
    public static void ProcessFileStorageRequest(this HttpRequest request, string path)
    {
        path = path.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });
        request.Path = "/productfile/download";
        string encodedPath = UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(path);
        request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?path={encodedPath}");
    }
```

Теперь метод download не вызывается.
Url меняется с
https://localhost:5000/path/download.html на такой
https://localhost:5000/path/file.exe/?path=path%2Ffile.exe

request изменяется, прилагаю скрин из дебага:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отладка пошаговая что говорит? Что содержит request, а что path? Точку останова ставили, или сразу вопрос на StackOverflow писать пошли?

Comment: @aepot, ставил. request изменяется. Добавил скрин в вопрос

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вам мидлварь? Насколько мне известно в ASP.NET Core достаточно мощный маршрутизатор. Можно обрабатывать то что вы здесь комбинируете прямо в эндпоинте. А так, кажется проблема не в этом методе, а в другом месте.

Comment: @aepot, для обработки разных типов файлов

Comment: Так зачем query, если можно это всё в path положить? Фронт по идее должен указывать верный путь, вот его и принимайте. Подмена пути здесь как бы лишняя. Если файлы статичные, то вообще лучше через статику это решать, вообще минуя web api на уровне http сервера. Просто данный мидлварь очевидно костыль.

Comment: @aepot, это сделано для того, чтобы все ссылки обрабатывались в одном месте. Т.е. на сайте есть много мест, где можно скачать файлы и файлы разных типов (exe, html, docx, image). И для разных типом разная логика. В данном случае не нужно везде встраивать на фронте вызов контроллера. При клике по ссылке урла обрабатывается в middleware

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 вот, почитайте, может что-то не так делаете. Может HttpRequest не нужно модифицировать, а есть какой-то другой способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл для себя решение:

```
public static void ProcessFileStorageRequest(this HttpContext context, string path, EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource)
{
    var endpoint = endpointDataSource.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e =>
    {
         var descriptor = e.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();

         return descriptor != null
                       && "download".Equals(descriptor.ActionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                       && "productfile".Equals(descriptor.ControllerName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    });

    if (endpoint == null)
    {
         throw new Exception("No valid endpoint found.");
    }

    context.SetEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```